# How to fix foreach forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

am quite new to programming and my app is returning an error when I do a forEach function. I have the following code in my controller.js

```
$scope.ajaxRequest = A.Game.get({action: 'game',id: user.id});
          $scope.ajaxRequest.$promise.then(function(){                                      
                $scope.ajaxRequest.game.forEach(function(entry) {
                    if(cards.indexOf(entry) !== -1) {
                        console.log('alredy in game');
                    } else {
                        if(entry.id != user.id){
                            cards.push(entry);                                
                            $scope.imageLocations.push(entry.photo);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

My console is giving me this error

```
ionic.bundle.js:26799 TypeError: $scope.ajaxRequest.game.forEach is not a function
    at controllers.js:2383
    at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:29132)
    at ionic.bundle.js:29148
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30400)
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:30216)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30508)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:24829)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:25027)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:24968)
```

Comment: Have you checked what `game` is?

Comment: What is `$scope.ajaxRequest.game`

Comment: Can you post what are the values in  `$scope.ajaxRequest.game` as @brk mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
          $scope.ajaxRequest.$promise.then(function(){                                      
                $scope.ajaxRequest.game.forEach(function(entry) {
```

looks fishy. Change it to

```
          $scope.ajaxRequest.$promise.then(function(result) {                                      
                result.forEach(function(entry) {
```

Now, I won't guarantee without seeing the result that it'll work, but this is the pattern of working with asynchronous calls and promises: in the `.then` block, put a function that uses the output of the previous one in the promise chain as argument. So at least this change

```
          $scope.ajaxRequest.$promise.then(function(result) {
```

(instead of `$scope.ajaxRequest.$promise.then(function() {`) is necessary.

Comment: Thanks so much for the assist, I have tried the code now I get this error: ionic.bundle.js:26799 TypeError: result.forEach is not a function